# Why does Application.Match behave inconsistently when run multiple times on the same data?

Tags: vba, excel

**The background:**

I have a workbook, `Outline.xlsm`, with a five-level hierarchy. In the first worksheet (`WS1`), the first three levels are described the first two columns, while the next two levels each have their own set of two columns:
[image: Outline sample]

In the second worksheet (`WS2`), there is no level 3, but everything else is the same. All cells are formatted as text.

I have some code that splits out each first-level section ("General thing") into its own workbook to allow users to make changes to the descriptions (and some other fields off to the right). The code in question then goes out and gets those new descriptions from each file and matches them to the ID number. Here is a sanitized version:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GatherData()

    'Set up for speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Get files to be processed
    Dim DataFolder As String
    Dim DataFile As String
    DataFolder = "\\SomeNetworkLocation"
    DataFile = Dir(DataFolder & "\GeneralThing*.xlsx")

    'Define ranges to search
    Dim WS1_L1Rng As Range
    Dim L2rng As Range
    Dim L3rng As Range
    Set WS1_L1Rng = Worksheets("WS1").Range("A2", "A" & Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set L2rng = Worksheets("WS1").Range("C2", "C" & Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set L3rng = Worksheets("WS1").Range("E2", "E" & Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)

    Dim WS2_L1Rng As Range
    Dim WS2_L2Rng As Range
    Set WS2_L1Rng = Worksheets("WS2").Range("A2", "A" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set WS2_L2Rng = Worksheets("WS2").Range("C2", "C" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row)

    Dim MatchPos As Variant
    Dim WS1_SearchRng As Range
    Dim WS2_SearchRng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    'Find and copy data
    Do While DataFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=DataFolder & "\" & DataFile
        With Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets("WS1")
            Set WS1_SearchRng = .Range("A2:" & "A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & ",C2:" & "C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & ",E2:" & "E" & .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
        For Each Cell In WS1_SearchRng
            If IsNumeric(Left(Cell.Value2, 2)) Then
                Select Case Cell.Rows.OutlineLevel
                    Case Is < 4
                        MatchPos = Application.Match(Cell.Value2, WS1_L1Rng, 0)
                    Case 4
                        MatchPos = Application.Match(Cell.Value2, L2rng, 0)
                    Case 5
                        MatchPos = Application.Match(Cell.Value2, L3rng, 0)
                End Select
                If IsError(MatchPos) Then
                    Debug.Print "WS1 " & Cell.Value2
                Else
                    MatchPos = MatchPos + 1
                    Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets("WS1").Range("A" & Cell.Row, "L" & Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Outline.xlsm").Worksheets("WS1").Range("A" & MatchPos, "L" & MatchPos)
                End If
            End If
            DoEvents
        Next Cell
        If Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        With Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets("WS2")
            Set WS2_SearchRng = .Range("A2:" & "A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & ",C2:" & "C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
        For Each Cell In WS2_SearchRng
            If IsNumeric(Left(Cell.Value2, 2)) Then
                Select Case Cell.Rows.OutlineLevel
                    Case Is < 4
                        MatchPos = Application.Match(Cell.Value2, WS2_L1Rng, 0)
                    Case 4
                        MatchPos = Application.Match(Cell.Value2, WS2_L2Rng, 0)
                End Select
                If IsError(MatchPos) Then
                    Debug.Print "WS2 " & Cell.Value2
                Else
                    MatchPos = MatchPos + 1
                    Workbooks(DataFile).Worksheets("WS2").Range("A" & Cell.Row, "I" & Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Outline.xlsm").Worksheets("WS2").Range("A" & MatchPos, "I" & MatchPos)
                End If
            End If
            DoEvents
        Next Cell
        End If
        With Workbooks(DataFile)
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
        DataFile = Dir
    Loop


    'Return to regular configuration
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**The problem:**

Often, when I go to run this code, `Application.Match` throws an error when it tries to match to anything in `WS2`. It usually works fine if I just kill the execution and start over on the same data (sometimes it takes a few tries). Very rarely, it can't find anything in `WS1` either; again, if I simply restart the execution it usually works just fine. Sometimes everything works great on the first try. Why does it not behave consistently?

Comment: `Range("N2")` in `Worksheets("WS1").Range("A2", "A" & Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)` would be one. `Worksheets` unqualified with a `Workbook` object would be another.

Comment: Add `On Error Resume Next` just before the `Application.Match` calls (add `On Error GoTo 0` just after them too!), and do `Debug.Assert Err.Number = 0` to break on error, then do `Debug.Print WS1_L1Rng.Parent.Name, WS1_SearchRng.Parent.Name` - does it output what you expect?

Comment: I've worked through all my `Worksheet` and `Range` references and made sure they're qualified properly. So far, so good. I still wonder why it was inconsistent, though. Did it sometimes just happen to be referring to the correct objects based on how things were left when the previous execution stopped?

Comment: Awesome; thank you for the quick and helpful solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch for implicit references to the active workbook/worksheet; what workbook/worksheet these instructions are referring to at run-time will depend on whatever workbook/worksheet is active at that time, and this is often responsible for such errors.

You can use [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) to easily locate them for you (and other potential code issues).

`Range("N2")` in `Worksheets("WS1").Range("A2", "A" & Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row)` would be one. `Worksheets` used unqualified with a `Workbook` object would be another.

[image: Rubberduck code inspections toolwindow]

The solution is to explicitly qualify them with a `Workbook` or `Worksheet` object reference.